# Mui components have no exports ('export default') error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just started creating a new react project, so I installed all necessary libs as mui, react-dom, .... I used all instruction found on the mui page.

After starting blank project without any filled pages I got errors that MUI modules have no exports (as you can see in the screenshot).
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1hpw.png)

I used all commands for installation from mui core web doc.:
`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`
`npm install @fontsource/roboto`
`npm install @mui/icons-material`
`npm install react-router react-router-dom`

Did I miss something?

Comment: is this error before or after you have added imports in your file for mui?

Comment: There's similar error in react-native-reanimated (https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3614#issuecomment-1825247784) You can check it out. Possible solutions will be to downgrade mui to stable previous version or use patch package. You could also ditch mui altogether and go for similar module, which there will be many.

Comment: Before adding, I don't have any imports, just a blank page.

Comment: did you try my suggestions from above comment?

Comment: Oh my gosh :D I just figured that I installed all modules into the wrong dir... x). Thx for the help anyway. Happy holiday

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you figure out that your question has no meaning anymore because the error is just a typo or a wrong `cd` post it as an update of your question, not here in comments, or just delete your question entirely.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a package issues. Try the steps below.

1. May be some caching problem , try closing all then open and run the project
2. If it doesn't work, delete the node moodules folder fully and run `npm install`, then start again
3. If still problem persist, then check update the node and npm and create a new project and check

Answer (score 0):

Ensure correct dependency versions and import statements. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json, then run npm install again. Check MUI documentation for accurate import syntax.